# E-Learning Change quantity to persons and add name and email fields

Tags: joomla-3.x

I’m here bugging for your help  ??? :o.

I’m making a small E-learning website and using VirtueMart for that I’m just stuck editing the shopping-cart form.

Since I’m selling courses I don’t need quantity but need persons when a teacher is ordering a course he need to specify how many students and depending of the student number I need to show field name and email for each before processing the order. But I wasn’t able to do that.

Joomla! 3.4.8

See picture below for more information.

Is there any help please!

[image: Original Form]

[image: Hoping for This Form]

Comment: Changing the word 'Quantity' to 'No. of Persons', can probably be done with a simple language override- https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: i was thinking this part wont be hard but second one ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're thinking about this the wrong way. It's not something that should be hacked into the checkout. You need what I believe is a modified Product Options plugin. Basically on the product page, it needs to ask you how many students, and then give you the fields to fill out there before you can add the item to your shopping cart. I'd suggest you find a Virtuemart developer who could write a plugin for you that could extend Virtuemart in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for the help i cant find any plugin who is doing this Already ?

Comment: There might but, but I have no idea. You'll probably have to find a developer to write one for you. Check the forums on the Virtuemart site.